# How do I "combine" JButton with JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

How do I "combine" JButton with JComboBox and place it on a JToolbar, as shown in this image:
[image]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a [custom renderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) I suspect, and have it display clickable buttons (with the appropriate actions attached, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Just create regular combo box and put image as an item. I did it once. Unfortunately I do not have a source code here but as far as I remember it was not a problem. You have to implement your custom 1ListCellRenderer`. Its method`getListCellRendererComponent()` should return for example Label with your image.